# Using Vuesax Sidebar component with a spa and am looking to auto detect page and set active property

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I am using vuesax sidebar component and don't know how to updated the computed property getActive

I am on laravel 5.7 in a vue spa and the active class if dedicated by the computed property and it changes when you click on each link but not by what page you are on. I have tried using a vue router link to and manually set the class with the class-active property that is used for router links

```
        <vs-sidebar-item to="/dashboard"  index="1" icon="menu">
         Dashboard
        </vs-sidebar-item>
        <vs-sidebar-item  to="/orders" index="2"  icon="all_inbox" >
            Orders
        </vs-sidebar-item>
```

https://i.gyazo.com/0053e00288c63e5c1eb1c77500d1a053.png

Right now if you click on the repective link it will change the active property but if you were to go to the url bar and change your page that way it will not be reflected in the navbar.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding some custom logic to the `afterEach` function within the Vue Router.

```js
router.afterEach((to,from) => {

  // Clear all buttons
  const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.vs-sidebar-item-active');
  btns.forEach( el => {
    el.classList.remove('vs-sidebar-item-active')
  });

  // Highlight correct button
  var item = document.querySelector("div.page-" + to.name);
  if (item) {
    item.classList.add('vs-sidebar-item-active');
  }
});
```

You need to add the appropriate class names to the `vs-sidebar-item`s. Here I've got classes of `page-***` to match the name of the route.